# Take a daily rolling mean of a seven day window for 30 minute sampled data

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to take a mean of a 7 day rolling window with 1 day increments of data that is collected at 30 minute intervals.
I have tried using `data.table` with `by` conditional statement with no success. Any guidane would be greatly appreciated.

```
# packages
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# Set set.seed to have reproducible sampling 
set.seed(42)

# Create some Data
start = ymd_hms("2014-01-01 00:00:00")
end = ymd_hms("2014-12-31 23:59:59")

# Create data with 30 minute intervals.
dat <- data.table(timestamp = seq(start, end, by = "30 min"),
                  sample1 = sample(1:20, 17520, replace = TRUE))

# Create date variable for merging datasets.
dat[, date := as.Date(timestamp)]

# Create data for 7 day window moving window with one day increments.
dat2 <- data.table(start = seq(start, end, by = "1 day"),
                  end = seq(start + days(7), end + days(7), by = "1 day"))

# Create date variable for merging datasets.
dat2[, date := as.Date(start)]

# mergre datasets.
dat <- merge(dat, dat2, by="date")

# Tried 
dat[, .(sample.mean = mean(sample1)), by = .(timestamp >= start & timestamp < end)]
#    timestamp sample.mean
# 1:      TRUE    10.46638

dat[, .(sample.mean = mean(sample1)), by = .(timestamp %in% c(start:end))]
#    timestamp sample.mean
# 1:      TRUE    10.40059
# 2:     FALSE    10.46767
#  Warning messages:
# 1: In start:end :
#  numerical expression has 17520 elements: only the first used
# 2: In start:end :
#   numerical expression has 17520 elements: only the first used

dat[, .(sample.mean = mean(sample1)), by = .(timestamp %between% c(start, end))]
#    timestamp sample.mean
# 1:      TRUE    19.00000
# 2:     FALSE    10.46589
```

Comment: Are the windows centered around minutes or days? I.e., are observations from 12:00 and 13:00 on the same day matched with the same surrounding window, or are the observations associated with the 13:00 observation pushed an hour forward

Comment: @ Frank thank you for the catch, updated so that random sampling is reproducible

Comment: @ MichaelChirico, the window are centered around days. Each window of seven days would have a total of 336 samples and should increment by one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your exact parameters, but here's the basic approach:

```
setkey(dat, date)

#pull the 7 previous days 
dat[ , dat[.(seq(.BY$date - 7L,
                 .BY$date, by = "day")),  
           #nomatch = 0L will exclude any requested dates outside the interval
           mean(sample1), nomatch = 0L], by = date]
#            date       V1
#   1: 2014-01-01 12.31250
#   2: 2014-01-02 10.94792
#   3: 2014-01-03 11.27083
#   4: 2014-01-04 11.10417
#   5: 2014-01-05 10.79167
#  ---                    
# 361: 2014-12-27 10.50260
# 362: 2014-12-28 10.52344
# 363: 2014-12-29 10.05990
# 364: 2014-12-30 10.03906
# 365: 2014-12-31 10.38542
```

Some possible tinkers:

- Change `7L` to whatever window you'd like; use positive if you want forward-looking averages
- If you want to go `by` `timestamp`, you'll have to adjust the `7L` to match whatever units (seconds/minutes/hours/etc)
- The extreme points of the interval are not technically correct since the window is shorter than requested; exclude `nomatch` and these points will return as `NA`
- Use `.(var = mean(sample1))` to name the output column `var`.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `library(zoo)`, but I guess it makes more sense to compute means at the day level first if you're going to ignore hours within the day, like `dat[, mean(sample1), by=date][, rmean := rollmean(V1, 7, fill=NA)]` and then merge back to `dat` by `date`.

Comment: @Frank off the top of my head those numbers should be the same, unless the number of observations in each day differs, in which case you should be weighting by the number of observations and come out with my answer anyway :p (up to the user though, depends on what you want to get out of the calculation)

Comment: Yeah, my point wasn't about whether your calculation is right, but about efficiency. You're taking the mean of 48*7 numbers for every value in the result, while you could instead be taking means of 7 numbers at a time (assuming stuff about weights and what the OP is after, etc.), plus rolling so the calculations aren't independent, of course.

Comment: @Frank gotcha. But your approach still requires taking the means of those other 48 numbers... seems if efficiency is paramount, the right approach is to... hmm, how to explain... get the mean for `y1`,...,`y7`, then add `(y8-y1)/n` instead of adding `y1`,..., `y6` again. Maybe this is what `rollmean` does...

Comment: Well I figure 48*365 + 365*7 < 48*365*7 (totally making up how "number of calculations" math works). Yes, I think that is what rollmean does.

Comment: @Frank would love to see a benchmark \*nudge\* \*nudge\* ;)

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I made a small modification to satisfy my needs `seq(.BY$date , .BY$date +7 , by = "day")`, but your solution was what I was looking for. @Frank, I see that taking a daily mean would speed things up, but my plan was to use a more complex function than a mean and wanted to make sure I got things to work before applying a more complex function. In the end, I applied non-linear regression `as.list(coef(nls(nee ~ (alpha*ppfd)/((1-(ppfd/ppfd.max)) + (alpha*ppfd/GPPopt)) + resp, start= list(alpha=0.0001, GPPopt=0.1, resp=0.1))` and work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
library(zoo)
daymeans = dat[, mean(sample1), by=date][, rmean := rollmean(V1, 7, fill=NA)]
dat[daymeans, rmean := i.rmean, on="date"]
```

This assumes that your data is already sorted by `date`; if not, use `keyby=date` instead of `by=date`. If you don't want to juggle intermediate objects, there is a one-liner:

```
# Michael Chirico's suggestion from the comments
dat[dat[, mean(sample1), by=date][, rollmean(V1, 7, fill=NA)], rmean := i.V1, on = "date"]
```

You may need to tweak the arguments to `rollmean` to fit your particular definition of the window. @eddi suggested that `runmean` from the caTools library is typically faster than zoo's `rollmean` and so is probably also worth a look.

---

Crude benchmark with the OP's example data:

```
dat2 = copy(dat)

# Michael's answer
system.time({
setkey(dat, date)
dat[ , dat[.(seq(.BY$date - 7L,
                 .BY$date, by = "day")),  
           mean(sample1), nomatch = 0L], by = date]
})

   user  system elapsed 
   0.33    0.00    0.35

# this answer
system.time({
daymeans = dat2[, mean(sample1), by=date][, rmean := rollmean(V1, 7, fill=NA)]
dat2[daymeans, rmean := i.rmean, on="date"]
})

   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

*Why it's faster*: Here, we're computing 365 means of 48 numbers and then a rolling mean of length 365; which is less computationally costly than making 365 merges to find 48*7 numbers and then taking the mean of the latter.

Comment: great! I wouldn't even bother creating the intermediate table, unless we're planning to re-use it... `dat2[dat2[ , mean(sample1), date][ , rollmean(V1, 7, fill = NA)], rmean := i.V1, on = "date"]` is a tad less digestible but still fine :)

Comment: nice answer; imo "standard" should be using `caTools::runmean` - waaay faster than `zoo::rollmean`

Comment: @eddi Oh, thanks, I've never heard of that, since I rarely/never rollapply stuff.